# Oracle: Update based on longest value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table with following columns:

```
**ITEM LOCATION COUNTRY DESCRIPTION**
100    KS1      SA     Apple iPhone 13 - 64GB
200    KS2      SA     Apple iPhone 13 - 64GB International Warranty
500    KS3      SA     Apple iPhone 13 - with Warranty
600    KS4      SA     Apple iPhone 13
300    KS1      BH     Apple iPhone 12 - 64GB
400    KS2      BH     Apple iPhone 12 - 64GB International Warranty
```

I want to update 100 and 200 with: Apple iPhone 13 - 64GB International Warranty
based on longest description and country
and same for 300 and 400 as: Apple iPhone 12 - 64GB International Warranty

How can I update Item/Country Description based on longest description of item/country

Comment: Would each country always have only two records?  We may need to see some more sample data here.

Comment: there will be multiple records for item/loc/country.  Edited with more records

Comment: "Longest" in what sense? Just "more characters"? That would be totally nonsensical; if two descriptions are "thing - 32GB" and "thing - 256GB" then the first would have to be replaced with the second, which makes no sense. If instead you mean "one is a **substring** of the other" then your example for country SA is wrong; the third row description is not a substring of the second row (due to the word `with`).

Comment: Longest in terms of more characters. There won't be difference in the differentiator like 32 or 64. There would just be additional information.

Comment: So items 100, 200, 500, and 600 all become 'Apple iPhone 13 - 64GB International Warranty', because they are all in 'SA', and this is their longest description. Correct?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Where are you stuck?

Comment: that's correct, i need the guidance on what should be the approach to start?

Comment: Well, an update happens to start with the word `UPDATE`. Then, as you want to update a particular table, you would add this table name after `UPDATE`. Then you want to update the column "description", so you add `set description =`. Haven't you even come that far? Anyway, I've posted an answer with two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Oracle's `KEEP LAST`:

```
update mytable t
set description = 
(
  select max(t2.description) keep (dense_rank last order by length(t2.description))
  from mytable t2
  where t2.country = t.country
);
```

Or stick to standard SQL:

```
update mytable t
set description = 
(
  select t2.description
  from mytable t2
  where t2.country = t.country
  order by length(t2.description) desc
  fetch first row only
);
```

(It seems weird that in your table there can only be one item per country and that the same item has multiple item numbers, but I guess that is just because you have tried to create simplified sample data for us, and your real data is quite different.)